# kotlin Как в списке объектов, поменять значение объекта

Tags: kotlin

kotlin  Как в списке объектов(ArrayList), поменять значение объекта(city.name), я написал данный пример, может у кого есть красивое решение, как  то не хотелось бегать по массиву

```
  var listCities: ArrayList<City> = ....            
     for (city in listCities) {
             if (city.name.equals("New York")) {
                        city.check = true
                        break
             }
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

при поиске элемент так или иначе будет проход по списку, но в стиле котлина можно сделать так `listCities.firstOrNull{it.name == "New York"}?.check = true`